# Using loop to fill Array with 5 given strings

Tags: java, arrays, loops, testing

I am looking for a way to fill in the string array when array length is given in a test function. For example when test gives length 100, I want these 5 string values to be printed throughout the array in loop so that it prints until the end. So far I managed to fill the array with first 5, however, I cannot find way to loop this through and test fails when higher array length is given. Thank you for any help!

```
public class Sid {
    public static String howMuchILoveYou(int nb_petals) {

        String Petals[]=new String[7];
        Petals[0]="zero index"; //cannot skip this for some reason
        Petals[1]="I love you";
        Petals[2]="a little";
        Petals[3]="a lot";
        Petals[4]="passionately";
        Petals[5]="madly";
        Petals[6]="not at all";


        return Petals[nb_petals].toString();
    }
}
```

TEST

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Random;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SampleTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assertEquals("I love you", Sid.howMuchILoveYou(1));
        assertEquals("a little", Sid.howMuchILoveYou(2));
        assertEquals("not at all", Sid.howMuchILoveYou(6));
        assertEquals("I love you", Sid.howMuchILoveYou(343));    //THIS ONE FAILS
    }
}
```

Comment: `return Petals[(nb_petals - 1) % 6 + 1];`? (You don't need the `.toString()` anyway).

Comment: Thank you Sir! This worked like a charm. May I please ask you to give me brief explanation how this worked out - why (nb_petals - 1) and what  "% 6 + 1" stands for? Or when can I find these things in java documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot comment so writing here...
According to my understanding, you are trying to execute the array in the loop.

```
 assertEquals("I love you", Sid.howMuchILoveYou(343));    //This will go outOfIndexBound
```

Your return statement in the method returns the array index value and since you have declared your array of size 7.

```
 return Petals[nb_petals].toString();
```

either you can have loop the array using the % operator

```
return Petals[(nb_petals - 1) % 6 + 1];
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. Could you please guide me to some java documentation where I can learn about the % operator? Somehow I cannot find anything specifically for this % operator. Thank you!

Comment: % operator returns the remainder of the expression. You can read more about it on https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

Comment: @backdoor you should explain why -1, why %, why 6, why +1 too.